# why imageView doesn't show the image that is converted from byte Array to image

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, display

I have converted some images from gallery to byte array and when I want to convert the byte arrays to image again , images are not displayed.

I have tested that with both Glide and Picasso libraries and also the command below but there were no result .

```
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

can any body help me??

Thanks!

Comment: Glide can show byte arrays, you dont need convert them.

Comment: I also enter the byte array directly to Glide without changing to bitmap but didn't work. I am sure the problem is from byte Array and but I want to know what it can be. Thanks

Comment: show the code for convert images to byte array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the mistake.
I had two variables in the database :

1. path of the image
2. byte Array of the image

the byte array variables wasn't complete and I had forgotten that.
so I displayed the image from the path of the image.

hope to be helpful.